# Correct initialization and graceful shutdown of FFTW3

Tags: fftw

I am using FFTW3 at several places in my software. However, these different places/functions/modules do not know about each other, and the order they are called (including their own initialization and cleanup) is impossible to predict. This results in a confusion when it comes to initialization and graceful shutdown of FFTW3.

- FFTW3 has a function called `fftw_init_threads()` which is supposed to be called just once before using any FFTW3 function. Since I don't know which of the application modules (that uses FFTW3) is initialized first, how can I make sure I only call this function once in the entire application?
- FFTW3 has a function called `fftw_cleanup_threads()` which is supposed to be called once at the very end of the application in order to clean up stuff. Any calls to FFTW3 functions after this call will fail. Again, since I don't know which subsystem of my application shuts down last, how can I make sure that I only call this function once at the very end?

One quick solution would be to blindly call the above two functions only at the beginning and end of my `main()` function respectively. However, this is bad design and not acceptable. The application itself should know nothing about FFTW3. Only the modules that are using FFTW3 should know about FFTW3. My current solution is to have an extra module which acts as a wrapper around the two functions and keeps track if FFTW3 has been initialised or shutdown. If a module requests FFTW3 initialization and FFTW3 is not initialized, then it will call `fftw_init_threads()`. Otherwise, it will just increase an internal counter and return. Something similar is implemented for the `fftw_cleanup_threads()` function. This solution appears to work if and only if the modules of the application use the wrapper in order to initialize and shutdown FFTW3.

So I wonder, how do you guys tackle this problem? Is there a way to query the FFTW3 library itself and check whether it is initialised or not? I wasn't able to find something in the documentation.

Thank you

Comment: It is safe to call **fftw_init_threads** multiple times, FFTW3 keeps track of its initialization status (`threads_inited` in `threads/api.c`) and won't repeat the initialization if the previous one is valid. You can call **fftw_cleanup_threads** multiple times, it knows not to repeat the process if there is nothing initialized. What you need to avoid in your application is calling cleanup() from module B while module A is still performing operations with FFTW. You'd need a global counter to keep track of how many modules are using FFTW and only call cleanup() when the last one finishes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment my friend. If you could copy-paste your comment into an answer, I would be happy to accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe to call **fftw_init_threads** multiple times, FFTW3 keeps track of its initialization status (global variable `threads_inited` in `threads/api.c`) and will not repeat the initialization if the previous one is valid.

You can call **fftw_cleanup_threads** multiple times, it knows not to repeat the process if there is nothing initialized.

What you need to avoid in your application is calling **fftw_cleanup_threads** from a module while others may still be using FFTW.

You could do that with a global counter to keep track of how many modules are using FFTW and only call fftw_cleanup_threads() when the last one is done.